# Why am I getting Windows Update error 1084 in Safe Mode with Networking?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, regedit, safe-mode

I've been having issues updating Windows 10 (error 0x8000ffff) . I was able to boot into safe mode with networking, but when I try to use windows Update, I get the error:
"Something went wrong. Try to reopen Settings later."

Following this, I go into services.msc and start Windows Update (which is not running), and I recieve the following error:

"Windows could not start the Windows Update service on Local Computer.

Error 1084: This service cannot be started in Safe Mode"

Now I've looked in the registry to see if there are any disabled Windows Update registry entries in Safe mode with networking (regedit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Safeboot/Network/) , but I can't seem to find any entries editing (enabling, disabling or referencing) wuauserv. I don't have any reference as to what should or should not be there, unfortunately.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: For clarity, I recieve this error when in safe mode with networking, connected to ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to Safe Mode, you need to start it with Networking (Ethernet).

Safe Mode alone does provide Networking, so no Internet and then so the error.

If updates present a further issue, open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  then

SFC /SCANNOW

Comment: Thank you for the tip! As I said, though, I was booted into safe mode with networking.

Comment: Try again restarting in Safe Mode with Networking. Launch Google to ensure this and then go to regular Windows Updates and try again.  You may need to run DISM and SFC.  Ensure networking is Ethernet.